# associative array inside array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array within an array as follows:

```
var array = new Array();

for ( i = 0; i < start.length; i++) {
   array[i] = {};
   array[i]['properties'] = {};

   for(property in start[i].properties ){
         //start[i].properties[property] --> ['Type'] = 'any string'
         array[j]['properties'][property] = start[i].properties[property];
   }
array[i]['id'] = start[i].getId();

}
```

So in the end I've an array with different elements like 'id' and an element as an array in this array (properties).

But when I use this array in another function, I can't reference to this inner array:

```
for (var v = 0; v < array.length; v++) {
   console.log(array[v][properties]['Type'])
}
```

The "array[v][properties]['Type']" is not defined..... Why?

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to access the variable `properties`, not the key `properties` The proper way to do that would be with `array[v].properties.Type`.

It's also better not to use bracket syntax unless you must - using dot syntax makes for more easily readable code.

The correct term for JavaScript btw is *object*, not *associative array*.

Comment: Thx but how do I iterate through all properties?

Comment: for(property in array[v].properties){
                    console.log(array[v].properties.property);
                }   doesn't work.....